# Problema com typescript + ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

boa noite, estou com o seguinte problema. eu tenho meu projeto em ionic e nele criei uma pasta só para as models.

```
app>model (o objetos do meu sistema)
       > minha-model-a.ts
       > minha-model-b.ts
       > minha-model-c.ts
       > all.ts
app>pages (minhas páginas HTML com os seus TS e SCSS)
       > minha-home.ts
       > minha-home.html
       > minha-home.scss
app>@meupacotepersonalizado (pasta com algumas classes em comum)
       > lib.ts
       > database
           > sql-manager.ts
           > database-creator.ts

app>app.ts (arquivo app do type script)
```

> Enfim vamos ao problema

Na minha pasta model, como vocês podem ver tem um arquivos chamado `all.ts` nesse arquivo eu exporto todas as minhas models para não precisar dar import em mais de um local. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
//arquivo all.ts da model
export {MinhaModelA} from './minha-model-a.ts';
export {MinhaModelB} from './minha-model-b.ts';
export {MinhaModelC} from './minha-model-c.ts';
```

> No meu `app.ts` eu importo a minha `database-creator.ts` eu instancio ela e depois chamo o método `executeCreator`;

```
//linha que cria gera o DatabaseCreator
let dbm = new DatabaseCreator();
dbm.executeCreator();
```

No meu `DatabaseCreator` é onde eu acredito que o problema ocorre. Aqui eu chamo o all.ts e importo todas as minhas classes pois elas tem em comum o método estático `getStructure` ele retorna uma string e eu executo no banco.

> Agora o problema
>
> ambiente-model.ts:16
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined__extends @ ambiente-model.ts:16
>   (anonymous function) @ cor-model.ts:314
>   .../@addpix/lib @ cor-model.ts:13s
>    @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:111../agendamento-model @ all.ts:2s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:15.../../model/all @ database-creator.ts:2s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:16../database-creator @ lib.ts:6s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:14../alertas/lib @ lib.ts:9s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:117.../@addpix/lib @ login-model.ts:1s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:130.../../@addpix/lib @ login-page.ts:2s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:19../@addpix/lib @ app.ts:4s @ _prelude.js:1e @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:1

**ambiente-model** é uma das minhas models porem quando vou na linha 16 só tem a `}` fechando a classe, se eu removo ela e coloco o login-model dá o mesmo problema. **Porém:** quando eu incluo o login-model diretamente pelo .ts dele e não pelo `all.ts` funciona.

Alguém pode me ajudar, essa maneira de exportação que fiz é a melhor?
Porque esse erro ocorre?
Há alguma solução rápida sem que eu altere toda essa estrutura?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta importar sem o sufixo `.ts`

```
export {MinhaModelA} from './minha-model-a';
```

Obs: Se não der certo, me avisa que vou apagar a resposta.